# Why would you need to return something to the input stream?

Tags: c++

The code was utilized to create a functioning calculator program. The whole thing's a bit long so I won't get into into all of it, but here's one portion:

```
Token Token_stream::get()
{
    if (full) { // do we already have a Token ready?
        full = false; // remove Token from buffer
        return buffer;
    }
    char ch;
    cin >> ch; // note that >> skips whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.)

    switch (ch) {
        case ';': // for “print”
        case 'q': // for “quit”
        case '(': case ')': case '+': case '–': case '*': case '/':
            return Token{ch}; // let each character represent itself
        case '.':
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
        case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
        {   
            cin.putback(ch); // put digit back into the input stream
            double val;
            cin >> val; // read a floating-point number
            return Token{'8',val}; // let ‘8’ represent “a number”
        }
        default:
            error("Bad token");

    }
}
```

Why would you need to put ch back into the input stream? Couldn't you just use the ch input instead of utilizing a whole new variable of val?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. However, there still is more data to be processed. Up to that point, `ch` will only have the first digit.

For example, if reading the input `123`, the `'1'` character will be read into `ch`. From there, the `'1'` will be put back onto the input and then the number `123` in its entirety will be read into `val`. If `cin.putback(ch);` wasn't called, then the `Token` returned would have the value `23` instead of `123`.

The other alternative would be to use the value in `ch` and then reading in the rest of the number that way. However, the author's intention was to use the safer and already-made method for reading into a `double`.

Comment: Uhh, sorry, I'm still a little confused. When you input 123, only '1' will be read into ch? Or would it proceed as, reads 1, puts it back, reads 2, puts it back, etc. In that case, why couldn't I just do away with the cases of 0-9 entirely and rely on cin >> val?

Comment: @blueyfooey `When you input 123, only '1' will be read into ch?` Yes. From that point on, it knows the next token is a number, so it reads in `123`. After that, the input has advanced past the `123` by reading the number. It will then process whatever is next.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. But wouldn't it still be simpler to just use cin >> val at that point?

Comment: @blueyfooey You first have to validate that there is a number there. For example, if `ch` had the letter `'a'` read in, what would it do with that? Its certainly not a number, so the `"Bad token"` error has to be shown.

Comment: What would happen if someone entered 125a? Since the first number was 1, would the program just assume, from 1 on, that everything else is just a number? Also, my last questions would be, if you don't put the number back into the input stream, where does it go and why isn't it accessed?

Comment: @blueyfooey It would read up to the `a` and then return `125`, so no error. The next token to be parsed would then get the `"Bad token"` error. And `val` is put into the `Token` and then whatever calls this method can use that new number that was read.

Comment: Where would the 1 remain, in the example of 123, if it's read as a token, and why couldn't it just be directly accessed if the case acknowledges its type? Is the 1 just read as a sort of test case so the program knows what it's dealing with?

Comment: @blueyfooey `why couldn't it just be directly accessed if the case acknowledges its type?` I addressed that at the end of the answer. `Is the 1 just read as a sort of test case so the program knows what it's dealing with?` Yes. And I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "where would the 1 remain".

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Assuming you entered 123 and did not use .putback(), only 23 would be read into val, correct? Is the 1 stored somewhere, or is it just ignored because it has fulfilled its function as a 'test case'. Also, for the 3 lines following after cin.putback(ch), would the ch (assuming that it passed as a floating point number) be automatically read into val, or would you need to re-enter it via cin >> val?

Comment: @blueyfooey ahh ok. Yes, `23` would be read in. The `'1'` would exist as a local variable until the method was left. And after it is put back to the front of the input, its purpose is done. So before the `putback` call, the input stream would look like: `['2', '3', ...]`. After, it would be `['1', '2', '3', ...]`. In that way, the value stored in `ch` is not needed when parsing into `val`.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I think I get it all now. Well, could you explain one more thing? After reading through the code multiple times, I'm not quite sure how the input stream of ch is automatically read into val. Wouldn't you have to reenter your input twice? So the initial was 123 for ch, then it asks for val through cin >> val, you'd have to retype 123, correct?

Comment: @blueyfooey don't forget that when you do `cin >> ch;`, it will only read 1 character. This character is then reinserted to the front of the stream with `putback`. So the initial was `'1'` for `ch` and `123` for `val`.

Comment: I see. So the ch only read '1' of the initial value in order to determine type, but val read the whole number. So this code wouldn't prompt a person to enter in their number twice then, as the number you initially attempted to use would just be automatically reinserted into val, am I correct?